# OS X 10.8 any way to remove stretched light frames from a stabilized video?

Tags: video, osx-mountain-lion, video-editing, codec

I stabilized my video with [Motion 5](https://www.apple.com/finalcutpro/motion/). The problem is it was taken with slow shutter so when the camera moved, the light in the frame are stretched and defaced.

Stabilized it just looks like the lights are being stretched in random directions. I use MacPorts so all the ffmpeg, avidemux, App Store and the web are all options.

Do you know of a good way to pull the defaced/stretched frames out without doing it frame by frame in streamclip?

Comment: Which technologie did you use to stabalize the video?

Comment: Motion 5... Maybe you recommend another stabilizer?

Comment: Yeah I knew already that you were using Motion 5. I want to know how you did in Motion, there are a couple of ways to stabilize in/with Motion 5